# Preloading content with grey bars like youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can anyone explain me, how I can add a content preloader to my site so that's look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vnGH.png]

How is this done?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a very clear question - why all the downvotes?  It asks a simple question and even shows an image of the desired result.  The first answer is great also.  Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: @RyanGriggs SO downvote Nazis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a **Loading placeholder**.

You can find some examples on many sites.

[Here](https://codepen.io/nurulishlah/pen/beEGVE) is an example on Codepen. As you can see, you can do it only with `HTML` and `CSS`. 
If you want other examples, you can find a lot of tutorials on YouTube with keywords **Loading placeholder tutorial**. If you want to make it more easily, you can use [this library](https://github.com/zalog/placeholder-loading).

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me!

Comment: You're welcome. 
Then please, up my answer and put it as the "accepted answer". This may help the others. Thank you.

Comment: unlikely it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: You still can put the answer as "Accepted answer" :)

Answer (score -1):

You can get better per loader from https://icons8.com/preloaders/

Comment: I know how to do this sort of preloader. But I want to know how to do something like this example on YouTube or Origin